# await is not defined (jQuery + CoffeeScript)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, async-await, coffeescript, sprockets

### versions

```
jQuery       2.2.4
CoffeeScript 2.4.1
Rails        5.1.7
Sprockets    4.0.0
```

### error

```
sample.source.coffee:33 Uncaught ReferenceError: await is not defined
    at countdown (sample.source.coffee:33)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (sample.source.coffee:36)
    at fire (jquery.source.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.source.js:3362)
    at Function.ready (jquery.source.js:3582)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.source.js:3617)
```

### code

```coffee
$(document).ready ->
...

    countdown = (seconds) ->
      for i in [seconds..1]
        console.log i
        await Promise.resolve 1
      console.log "Blastoff!"
      
    countdown(3)
```

In CoffeeScript, a function with `await` keyword in it is automatically considered as a `async` function, so `async` is not declared in the above code. -> https://coffeescript.org/#async-functions

Comment: `await` is only valid in an `async` funtion. Go through that link you have again. You have syntax error in your code as well.

Comment: the doc quite literally says `there’s no need for an async keyword; an async function in CoffeeScript is simply a function that awaits.` Also the example in the doc is written without `async`.

Comment: You might be using an outdated version of coffeescript. Is the coffeescript version you have listed there from `npm` or is it a `gem`? What output do you get from `coffee -v`?

Comment: thanks for the heads up. It was 1.12.1. The version I listed was that of `coffee-script` gem, but the gem whose version is in sync with CoffeeScript was `coffee-script-source` and that was 1.12.1. Given that's the latest version for `coffee-script-source`, it seems  installing Coffee Script 2 takes some manual work...